# Install latest version of Unity in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity

Is there anyway I can install the latest Unity (used in Ubuntu 13.04) in Ubuntu 12.04?
I do not want to upgrade my super stable 12.04 just to get the Unity.

Comment: Guys help me to fix this.